# How can I wait until a specific text is loaded?

Tags: python, html, selenium, wait

This is the page I try to collect data (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) using Selenium and Python 3.6. What I would like to do is to select each drop down menu of the first row and click 'search button', and then start to collect data when the page is loaded.

[image]

The part I got stuck is that the crawler "waits" until the stock list is refreshed. I can't find how to figure out the page is completed to be refreshed.

I know I could use "waits.until(EC....)" function in Selenium. The thing I can't figure out is "the clue" the page is refreshed. I tried with the text of the item in the last drop-down menu. But sometimes the list title doesn't have that text in it.

Please help.

Comment: What specific data are you trying to collect from that page?

Comment: I would like to collect all the data from each stock list such as img url, title, description, year/month, price, etc. I completed to make the crawler to collect the data, but I got stuck in code to make it "wait" until new page is loaded.

Comment: Why do you want to wait? Did you try to scrape data without `ExplicitWait`? Some data was missed or what?

Comment: When I select the drop-down menu and click search button, there should be some delay time to complete the page re-load.

Comment: But why you need that delay? All required info is already present in page source. When you click "Search" you send `GET` request for completely new `HTML` document, but not `XHR` request. And you don't need to wait until page completely rendered to just get attributes of target elements